# substring and the indexOf method

Tags: vb.net, substring

My assignment in Visual Basic 2010 is to build a order form that has two text boxes, one for the name and the other for the address.

And we're suppose to use the `IndexOf` method on the address.

I understand that `IndexOf` returns the position of a character and the number of characters.

What would be the purpose of using the `IndexOf` method on the address in this instance?

I don't understand what I would be searching for when the user types in it's address that's going to be numbers and string characters.

I think I understand what the `IndexOf` method does, somewhat, but why and what would I use it to achieve?

Comment: Perhaps this would be a good question for whoever gave you the assignment. Usually assignments say something like "use IndexOf on the address to ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd typically use `IndexOf` to -

See if a string contained something

```
If someString.IndexOf("Avenue") > - 1 Then
   'do something
End If
```

Get the start position of a value in a string , this could then be used to extract part of the string. e.g. `someString.Substring(someString.IndexOf("@"),10)` would get then next ten characters starting from where the "@" character was found in your string.

Bear in mind you'll always need to handle scenarios where `IndexOf` will return -1 if it does not find the string your searching for, so your code will have to handle that eventuality.

Comment: That was helpful. So if Dim strAddress As String = Los Angeles. In a indexOf function. Could I code this: If MyExample.Text = strAddress.IndexOf(0,11) Then. Would that be correct if I'm trying to search for Los Angeles as a condition to apply a discount, for example?

Comment: If you were trying to search for `Los Angeles` you'd need `MyExample.Text.IndexOf("Los Angeles")` if the result of that was greater than -1 then you'd know the `MyExample` string contained the text 'Los Angeles'. Bear in mind that that example is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework question, I will answer with a question or several:

- How would you normally enter a full address into a text box?
- How would each part of the address be distinguishable from another?
- Once you figure out how this can be done, think about `IndexOf` again.